# How can you diagnose when the Internet drops on macOS while Wi-Fi has full bar signal?

Tags: macos, network, wifi, airport

I have a 2018 Mac mini that I bought last August and I never had a problem with it. About a week or two ago I started having a problem where [my WiFi stays on but I suddenly loose the internet conection](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/177873/), other computer and devices in the network work just fine and usually turning the Wi-Fi off and on again works, but after a while it happens again and I have tried everything to my knowledge to no avail. I have tried renewing DHCP lease, changing the MTU, deleting network .plist files to restart the preferences, creating a new location, forgeting the network and adding it again, restarting my router and creating a new network, changing the DNS, restarting PRAM and SMC and reinstalling macos.

I realize a silver bullet fix might not be easily recommended, so what kind of process or guide would help diagnose the problem?

Comment: It’s a long shot, but if you [disable wds on the router](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/120006/) does this clear up? Also, if you edit in a [little of the frequency. Once a week, once an hour, etc..](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/316659/)  that might help focus any  suggestions.

Comment: Would you assist me in how to both of those things? I have an AirPort Extreme 802.11n (3rd Generation) but I'm not network-savvy.

Comment: It’s best to ask more narrow questions. Why not ask each as a focused question and link them here in the comments? You need to detail which router you have or hire someone to do the work for WDS. I’m not sure that the other “both” is - I don’t know any better triage than following the linked articles unfortunately so that’s why I linked instead of made a new answer.

Comment: It looks like there a quite a few people with the same problem. Do you have any USB devices (e.g. a hub) attached to the Mini which you could disconnect? Does the problem coincide with anything, for example someone using a microwwave oven? Can you put the Mini somewhere else, in particular somewhere it will have an easy time staying cool?

Comment: I don't have anything conected besides the power conector and an HDMI cable, I use wireless mouse and keyboard. I read somewhere that date time preferences could somehow interfere with Wi-Fi and I remember the problem started at the beginning of January so could that have anything to do with it? my date and time are set automatically so I don't know what I could do about that.